# How do generate a UITableViewController that is filled with all the files in the app document folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

My app is saving certain files. I need to be able to load the files up and show in a UITableViewController.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the Documents folder and then use that to populate a table view.

---

To get the contents of a directory (and perform other file operations), you can use the [NSFileMananger](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Specifically, look into the [`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:Error`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/contentsOfDirectoryAtPath%3aerror%3a) method and the similar ones.

Essentially, what you want to do is to store those results in an array or collection and then display them in the table view. You can use the standard UITableViewDelegate and data source methods.